# Why am I not capturing this JSON in my controller?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

So I'm passing a an array of objects like

```
{ QuestionId: 24,
  AnswerVal: -1,
  PartnerId: "e0e8035d-046a-45c5-b7e5-7986865ce37c",
  VersionId: 1 }
```

and my controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitAnswers ( List<AnswerSubmission> A )
```

where `AnswerSubmission` is defined by

```
public class AnswerSubmission
{
    public Guid PartnerId { get; set; }
    public int AnswerVal { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int VersionId { get; set; }
}
```

It's not working as I get empty response from

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Answers/SubmitAnswers',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(Answers),
    complete: function ( retobj ) {
        console.log(retobj);
    }
});
```

if I make my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitAnswers ( List<AnswerSubmission> A )
{
    return Json(A);
}
```

as a test.

Comment: Add the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option to you ajax.

Comment: Replace the data parameter on Ajax call: data: { '': Answers }

Comment: That's not an _"array of objects"_, you're sending an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> { 
>   QuestionId: 24,
>   AnswerVal: -1,
>   PartnerId: "e0e8035d-046a-45c5-b7e5-7986865ce37c",
>   VersionId: 1 
>   }

Is not an *"array of objects"*, it's an object.

So *in addition* to `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` as commented by @Stephen Muecke

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Answers/SubmitAnswers',
    dataType: 'json',
    //add this
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(Answers),
    complete: function (retobj) {
        console.log(retobj);
    }
}).done(function (d) {
        console.log(d); //probably what you're really looking for..
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitAnswers(AnswerSubmission A)//an object, not an array of objects
{
    return Json(A);
}
```